# EntityFramework6 / Npgsql: how to translate orderBy nulls last into SQL query

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am using EntityFramework6.Npgsql and am working with tables with several million records. Some of the entities have a `timestamp` / `DateTime` column which allows `null` values. Users often need to sort on this column and would like to show `null` values last in both `asc` and `desc` sorting. The column has two indizes for both sorting types with both of them set to `nulls last`

I know in SQL I can add `order by "DateColumn" desc nulls last` and postgres uses the appropriate index and the query returns (paged, e.g. 25 records) results in a few milliseconds.

With EntityFramework however, in order to sort descending with nulls last, I have to add something like this:

```
entities.MyEntity
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.DateColumn.HasValue)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.DateColumn)
```

This however translates to a query that contains something like this for sorting:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN ("Extent1"."DateColumn" IS NOT NULL) THEN (TRUE)
        ELSE (FALSE)
    END AS "C1"

...

ORDER BY "C1", "DateColumn" DESC
```

Which works as intended but the query takes several seconds (instead of several milliseconds) to execute, as it is unable to use the index.

I tried adding an index to the column with that same expression, but postgres does not seem to use the index when executing the query.

What options do I have to write a query in EntityFramework / Npgsql that can translate into the desired SQL (`order by "DateColumn" desc nulls last`)? Is there a way to intercept/overwrite how Linq queries are translated into SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

While still unable to have Linq generate an SQL query that sorts with `nulls last`, I was able to create a combined index for the null-check and the date column itself, that is being used by postgres:

```
CREATE INDEX "MyTable_IX_DateCombined"
  ON "MyTable"
  USING btree
  ((
  CASE
    WHEN "DateColumn" IS NOT NULL THEN true
    ELSE false
  END) DESC, "DateColumn" DESC);
```

Since I'd have to create an additional index in either case, I consider this solution good enough at this point.

Comment: Note the request to add this as a feature for Entity Framework Core (not 6.x, where this is likely not possible: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/326

If you're interested go vote on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! We have same but simpler index

```
CREATE INDEX "MyTable_IX_DateCombined"
 ON "MyTable"
 USING btree
 (("DateColumn" IS NOT NULL ) DESC, "DateColumn" DESC);
```

because our version of ef core 6 translates query so

```
ORDER BY ("DateColumn" IS NOT NULL ) DESC, "DateColumn" DESC
```